# What font is used for the title on the cover of the revised "Clanbook: Nosferatu"?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, content-identification, fonts

In the old Clanbooks, each clan had pretty much its own Font for the title.

What was the font used in the (revised) Clanbook Nosferatu title?

[image: Title splat from Clanbook Nosferatu, Revised, 2000]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My best guess would be [TM Unicorn TTF](https://www.wfonts.com/font/tm-unicorn) or a substantially similar font.

[image: Word Nosferatu written in linked font]

[This unofficial listing of Vampire fonts](https://www.kismetrose.com/vtm/VampireFonts.html) seems to support my guess as well.

Comment: Can you support your guess, perhaps by comparing relevant elements of the linked font (e.g. unique aspects of how certain letters are rendered) to those in the image shown in the question?

Comment: I added the image of the word Nosferatu in that font directly to your answer. It sure looks similar, except some letters are much narrower. But for one word, such adjustments may well be done by hand.

Comment: Accounting for altered aspect ratio, the shape of the letters is damn near identical. If it's not this font specifically, whatever it actually is is either a derivative of or antecedent to this font.

Comment: I don't know why it was my guess. It just looked like the font. I've used it a few times. I didn't do any comparisons. But, a little googling, I did find this: http://www.kismetrose.com/vtm/VampireFonts.html and whoever keeps that site seems to agree that is the correct font. I'm not sure where they got their information from.

Comment: R and T don't match up sadly: the R here goes higher, the T is flat, where the title page doesn't have it - but it is *damned* close.7

Comment: @Trish It's possible those small changes were made by the graphic designer when the clanbook was laid out.